# Sharepoint 2019 visual webpart with SQL database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, visual-web-part

We are planning implement SharePoint 2019 on-prem to replace existing SP 2010 intranet . 
we have few SP visual webparts with  SQL data sources that was build using VB.net .
we like to know if it is possible to migrate SP2010 .wsp solution to SP2019 (webpart -server side /Client side)  or any clear guidelines/instructions 
how to develop visual webpart solutions (with SQL database) for SP 2019 on-premise .

I do apologize for my lack of understanding all this different framework . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If the SharePoint 2010 WSP solution was developed correctly, it will still work just fine in SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019.

It has to be noted that there is no OOB "upgrade" procedure that will convert the old source code for SP 2010 to the new one for SP 2013/2019.

The most popular reason old webparts are "upgraded" is that developers just hardcoded in there something like URLs, server names, connection strings, etc. Meaning they didn't follow good practices.

If you want to "upgrade" your webpart for whatever reason, you will need:

- SharePoint 2013, 2016 or 2019 Dev Server. Note that a webpart created for SP 2013 will be no different from webpart created for SP 2019.
- Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017 or 2019

In Visual Studio, simply create a new Solution project and add your code from the old solution and refactor it if needed. You can also "upgrade" your SP 2010 solution source code with "find and replace". But recreating a solution from scratch is faster.